# How to create a new folder using php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a new folder using PHP.

What I have so far:

```
$dir = dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).'/images/1/thumb'; 
if( is_dir($dir) === false )
    { 
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }
```

But the folder is not created. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to give `path` as `$dir` not the URL.Your `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` produces URL

Comment: Use relative path instead of absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give absolute path as url will not work in file and directory handlig.

so your new function will be like that

```
   mkdir('./images/1/thumb', 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $structure = './images/1/thumb';

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 

// to mkdir() must be specified.

if (mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
echo "Folder Created";
}else{
echo "Not Created";

} ?>
```

Comment: this is essentially the same code as in the question

Comment: @Oleg Estekhin : please check properly my answer is different from question,and if you copy and run my answer it's creating the folder.

Comment: @Oleg Estekhin :first check properly and then downvote the answer

Comment: @SoniyaKaliappan : so can you upvote my answer.someone without reason downvote my answer :(